# Unit Testing IHttpActionResult without casting return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a web API controller with a method like (truncated non-relevant bits):

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Order(int orderId) {
    // ...
    var response = new OrderResponse {
        Data = orderData,
        Message = message,
    };
    return Json(response);
}
```

I have a test that makes an assertion about the value of the expected `JsonResult<OrderResponse>.Content`.

Since the interface `IHttpActionResult` does not declare `Content`, I am currently casting the result in the unit test to a `JsonResult`.  However, this requires my test to know how the return is implemented in my controller, and I'd like to achieve looser coupling, if possible, so that my tests don't break if the response implementation changes.

```cs
[TestCase(-1, "The requested order (-1) was not found.")]
public void Test_Returns_NotFound_For_NonExistent_OrderId(int orderId, string expected) {
    var sut = new OrderController()
    // ...
    var result = sut.Order(orderId);

    // I am doing this to get access to `Content`:
    var materializedResult = result as JsonResult<OrderResponse>;

    expected.Should().BeEquivalentTo(materializedResult.Content.Message)
}
```

Comment: what are  you testing if you are not testing the actual response type from the controller?

Comment: Maybe you could change to [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) as the most common results are coming from this interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short?  Only use the methods that are available on the interface!

```
  var controller = new ValuesController();
  controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
  controller.Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
  var result = controller.Get(1);

  var response = result.ExecuteAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
  String deserialized = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  Assert.AreEqual("\"value\"", deserialized);
```

`IHttpActionResult` only contains one method -- `ExecuteAsync`.  So call it!  It'll return an `HttpResponseMessage` which will contain the Content you're looking for.  You'll probably want to make your unit tests async and actually await the result, but this should work to get you started.

Comment: I see -- I noticed that there is a generic `ReadAsAsync` so I deserialized into my response object - `response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrderResponse>().Result;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning `Json(response)`, return `Ok(response)`. You don't need to specify that it is formatted as JSON. If the client requests JSON, the application will return JSON. (That's assuming you're using default content negotiation.)

Then in a unit test you can retrieve your data from the returned `IHttpActionResult` like this:

```
var actionResult = sut.Order(orderId);
var orderResponse = actionResult.ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken())
    .Result.TryGetContentValue(out OrderResponse expected);
```

...and you can assert whatever you want with `expected`, and your test doesn't make any assumption about how the response is formatted.